# How to find and replace name attributes with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="foo">
  <input name="moobar" />
  <input name="foobar" />
</div>
```

How do I replace all "oo" in the names found in `$('.foo');`? e.g. div.replace('oo', 'aa') => moobar => maabar

Answer (score 6):

```
$('.foo input[name*="oo"]').attr('name', function(_, name){
    return name.replace('oo', 'aa')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/V4FK6/)